# Accessing response status after it is sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I'm working on a feature to store requests made to specific endpoints in my app.

```
after_action :record_user_activity
def record_user_activity
  return unless current_user
  return if request.url =~ /assets|packs/
  @session.navigation.create!(
    uri: request.url,
    request_method: request.method,
    response_status: response.code.to_i,
    access_time: Time.now
  )
end
```

The problem is that, even if we get an error response, when getting the `response.code` at this point (`after_action`), the response code is still a 2xx. I imagine it's probably because the server hasn't yet faced whatever problem it may face during the data access process.

How can I properly store the status code that was actually *sent* to the user?

Answer (score 0):

The rails logs already store the requests and responses.  If you just need to track all user requests, you can simply add the user id to your logs.  Unless there's a specific reason to keep this data in the DB, which would grow exponentially with the amount of user activity, add this to either `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/production.rb`

```
MyAppName::Application.configure do
  #...whatever you already have in configs
  # then add the following line
  config.log_tags = [
          -> request { "user-#{request.cookie_jar.signed[:user_id]}" }
      ]
end
```

Then you can tail the logs and use grep, or write some other processes to parse over the logs with other analytics.  There are many tools available for this type of work. But here's a basic example

```
tail -f logs/production.log | grep user-101 
# this would show all log requests from user with id 101
```

If you still need this however, you may wanna try `prepend_after_action` instead, see

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-prepend_after_action

Comment: I actually need to store activity specific to one controller to be able to track certain user behavior. I still need to somehow get the sent response and access its status code in a controller method, or a solution that's in line with this.

Comment: Ok, so maybe have a look at `prepend_after_action` see updated answer